# Chemfig artifacts next to bonds

Tags: tikz-pgf, chemfig

When drawing reaction schemes with chemfig I get unwanted small dots next to certain molecules. These dots remain the same size weither I zoom in the document or not.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

%\schemedebug{true}
\schemestart[][west]
    \chemfig{CO}
    \+
    \chemfig{M}
    \arrow{->}
    \chemfig{M=[:90]CO}
    \arrow{->}
    \chemfig{M=[:90]C}
    \arrow{0}[,0]\+\arrow{0}[,0]
    \chemfig{M=[:90]O}
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

When using the \schemedebug{true} option I notice that the artifacts are now represented with blue dots so there must be a connection between the two. If anyone has an idea what the blue dots represent, that would also help!

```
article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
chemfig.sty    2012/02/24 v1.0f Draw molecule with an easy syntax
tikz.sty    2010/10/13 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76)
pgf.sty    2008/01/15 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.12)
pgfrcs.sty    2010/10/25 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.24)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
pgfrcs.code.tex
pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 graphics configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/message (HO)
ltxcmds.sty    2011/04/18 v1.20 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
pgfsys.sty    2010/06/30 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.37)
pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2008/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.1)
pgffor.sty    2010/03/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.18)
pgfkeys.sty    
pgfkeys.code.tex
pgffor.code.tex
tikz.code.tex
supp-pdf.mkii
***********
```

Comment: No dots here: can you add `\listfiles` to your input, and the edit the resulting `*Fiel List*` from your log into the question?

Comment: I have added what I think you asked for

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an issue which is not reproducible with an up-to-date TeX system.